# Clarification on Item Types and Creating Items SavedSearch in NetSuite

Tags: filter, types, netsuite, saved-searches

I'm currently working with NetSuite and trying to understand the different item types. Specifically, I want to confirm if my understanding is correct regarding the following item types:

Serialized Inventory items,
Non-Serialized Inventory items,
Services for Sale items (Services)

## My assumption:

is (serialized inventory items ) === inventory item,
(non-serialized inventory items) === non- inventory item,
(service items) === services

Are these item types all distinct in NetSuite, or are some of them related or considered the same?

Additionally, I'm trying to create an items file based on a saved search in NetSuite, and I need to include the following item types in the file:   Serialized Inventory items, Non-Serialized Inventory items, and Services for Sale items (Services).

I have attempted to use the type filter in the search criteria as shown below:
Type is Any Of Inventory Item, Non-Inventory Item, Services

However, I'm unsure if this filter correctly captures the required item types. Can anyone provide advice or guidance on how to accurately create the saved search to include these specific item types in the items Saved search?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can include for the serialized inventory items a filter called "Is Serialized Item" - (review the [records browser](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2023_2/script/record/account.html) for further info on available columns).

I'd recommend you use expressions and create your filter as:
(type anyof inventoryitem AND isserialitem is T) OR (type anyof noninventory, service)